# how increase the maximum number of simultaneously existing ports in erlang using windows

Tags: syntax, erlang, syntax-error, command-prompt

i am using windows and i want to Set the maximum number of simultaneously existing ports to 65536. in `Erlang` docs it says:

[ERLAG doc here , visit for syntax](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html)

> +Q Number|legacy
>    Sets the maximum number of simultaneously existing ports for this system if a Number is passed as value. Valid range for
>   Number is [1024-134217727]
>
> On Windows the default value is set to 8196 because the normal OS
>   limitations are set higher than most machines can handle.
>
> If legacy is passed as value, the legacy algorithm for allocation of
>   port identifiers will be used. Using the legacy algorithm, identifiers
>   will be allocated in a strictly increasing fashion until largest
>   possible identifier has been reached. Note that this algorithm suffers
>   from performance issues and can under certain circumstances be
>   extremely expensive. The legacy algoritm is deprecated, and the legacy
>   option is scheduled for removal in OTP-R18.

i used below syntax but it gives me syntax error, whats wrong ?

[image]

Comment: `+Q` is an `erl` command-line option, not an Erlang shell command.

Comment: @SteveVinoski may you explain more ? where should i use this command ?

Comment: You probably ran `erl` or `werl` to get an Erlang shell to show in your question, right? If so, you add the `+Q` and its parameter to that command. I'm not a Windows user so I don't know all the details of how users start Erlang there.

Comment: simply start erlang in a command window typing: werl +Q 65536

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my reputation doesnt allow me to just comment, I'll just answer...

If you dont like to start the erlang VM through a batch script or the command window, you can create a link to the werl.exe and edit the Command it executes by right clicking and changing the Properties of said link. For example:

Default link Target: "C:\Program Files (x86)\erl5.10.4\bin\werl.exe"

Would become: "C:\Program Files (x86)\erl5.10.4\bin\werl.exe" +Q 65536

This also allows for different configurations for different projects/applications.

Another way would be, to use .bat scripts instead of a link.

Comment: Thanks , I got the point I tried erl +Q 65536 , it changes the max port but when I close the opened window and open it again it return the default value. I dont know how to save changes

Comment: You have to pass +Q 65536 every time you open the window. Did you open it again by also running "erl +Q 65536"?

Comment: Hmmm... You know, I am using Erlang for rabbitmq server, rabbitmq read Erlang configurations. So it should not be open every time. I want to change Erlang config once. And rabbitmq could accept 65536 port not the default value.

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html This article describes how to change the arguments rabbitmq passes to erlang during startup. Look for RABBITMQ_SERVER_ERL_ARGS or RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS

Comment: Thanks I will take a look.